suspension map between homotopy groups of spheres
Let $p$ be an odd prime. For $n\geq 3$, suspension map $\Sigma:\pi_{n+2p-3}(S^n;p)\to\pi_{n+2p-2}(S^{n+1};p)$ is an isomorphism on $p$-primary part and $\pi_{2p}(S^3;p)=\mathbb{Z}/p$. Meanwhile, there is a theorem of Serre saying that $\pi_{4k-1}(S^{2k})$ contains a $\mathbb{Z}$ direct summand, which means if $4k-1-2k=2p-3$ i.e. $k=p-1$, then the $(4p-5)$-th homotopy group of the $p$-localized $(2p-2)$-sphere $S^{2p-2}_{(p)}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p$. My question: Is there a general formula for the suspension map $\Sigma:\pi_{4p-5}(S^{2p-2}_{(p)})\cong\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\to\mathbb{Z}/p\cong\pi_{4p-4}(S^{2p-1}_{(p)})$ ?

Have you considered asking this question over on MO as well? This strikes me like a suitable question for there as well (but my knowledge about the unstable theory is admittedly quite limited).
